# Can I get the referencing list of each frame of h.264 using ffmpeg or ffprobe?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, ffprobe

I want to get the referencing list of each frame of h.264 video. For example, I want to get the list as following:

Frame 0: Reference frame 0

Frame 1: Reference frame 0

Frame 2: Reference frame 1,3

Frame 3: Reference frame 0

Can I get the referencing information above using ffmpeg or ffprobe? I have googled but got little harvest. Or are there any software can do this? Thanks for your relpy!

Answer (score 3):

The direct printing of List 0 and List 1 references is hidden by a preprocessor guard. However, you can get close by printing the decoder's mem mgmt operations

```
ffmpeg -debug mmco -i INPUT -an -f null -
```

This will print readouts in the following format.

```
[h264 @ 000001c7cf382340] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 000001c7cf382340] short term list:
[h264 @ 000001c7cf382340] 0 fn:7 poc:65552 000001c7d1090d80
[h264 @ 000001c7cf382340] 1 fn:6 poc:65556 000001c7d0da4600
[h264 @ 000001c7cf382340] 2 fn:5 poc:65548 000001c7d0b00500
[h264 @ 000001c7cf382340] long term list:
```

The `fn` refers to the frame index in decoding order. The `poc` is the display order (with a base offset of 65536).

Comment: Thanks very much！But I still don't know how to get the reference list using the decoding order and display order. For example, the display order is 0,1,2 and the decoding order is 0,1,2.  Then there are two 2 possibilities. One is frame-1 reference frame-0 and frame-2 also reference frame-0; Or frame-1 reference frame-0 and frame-2 reference frame-1. So I think it may be difficult to get the reference list of each frame using only the decoding order and display order. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Sorry the stackoverflow said that I " need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote" so I can't use the  thumbs-up button!